# how to catch response from server ping and sent alert

Tags: ksh, ping, ldap

I have the below command I'm running:

```
ping ldap.corp.XXXXX.com
```

LDAP Server up:

```
Pinging ldapeu.corp.XXXXX.com [XX.XXX.XXX.XX] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from XX.XXX.XXX.XX: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=252
```

LDAP Server down:

```
ping: ldap.corp.XXXXX.com: Name or service not known
```

how can I implement code in the KSH file to identify when the LDAP server is down?

Comment: Unsolicited advice: pinging a *server* is an *approximation* of a *service* being available. Consider doing LDAP checks if it's the LDAP service you care about.  Note also that "name or service not known" is a separate issue from a server being down. DNS resolution should not normally fail if a system is shut down; perhaps that name points to a load balancer that stops resolving when back-end nodes are unavailable.

Comment: @JeffSchaller you are right, it's best to check the service. What would be the simplest command line to test ldap basics, say reach the server and connect?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani sounds like a (potential) new question! :)   (check to see if we have one, first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` returns a different exit code depending on how successful it is. There are multiple implementations of ping that may behave slightly differently, but quoting from [one of their manpages](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/buster/iputils-ping/ping.8.en.html)

> If **ping** does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with
>   code 1. If a packet *count* and *deadline* are both specified, and fewer
>   than *count* packets are received by the time the *deadline* has arrived,
>   it will also exit with code 1. On other error it exits with code 2.
>   Otherwise it exits with code 0. This makes it possible to use the exit
>   code to see if a host is alive or not.

Other than 0 for success and non-zero for failure, your ping may use different values; you can check with `echo $?` after it runs.

There are also other ping programs (e.g., `fping`) intended for monitoring.

So you can do something as simple as:

```
if ping -c 2 ldapeu.corp.XXXXX.com ; then
    echo up
else
    echo down
fi
```

(You could use something like `if ping … >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then` to get rid of all the messages `ping` prints.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ping`'s exit value to know if the host is up:

```
0 everything ok
1 no response or lost packages
2 other errors (unable to resolve is one of them)
```

So, this for example:

```
ping -c 5 hostname || error_script.sh
```

will run `error_script.sh` only if something went wrong.

Comment: what 5 means here?

Comment: 5 is the number of pings sent. Without it `ping` would keep on sending them. Try `man ping` to see other options.